# Input redirect using IDE (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, dev-c++

How do I use Input Redirect using an IDE (Windows)? I already tried with both Code::Blocks and Orwell Dev C++ the following program arguments, and it didn't worked:

```
./a.out < Input.txt
xxx.exe < Input.txt
< Input.txt
./Input.txt
```

Using Dev C++ I printed all the argv, and I got the following

```
main.exe
./a.out
<
Input.txt
```

So, the IDE was passing the argument, but it wasnt't reading anything from the file. What could be the problem here? The Windows, the IDE or something else? I tried with *./a.out < Input.txt* using a Code::Blocks and Linux and worked fine, so I'm really clueless.
Another IDE that you know how to input redirect could solve my problem too.
Thanks.

Comment: Hmya, don't get your hopes up.  MSVC supports it.  But that isn't very trivial, it normally requires the command processor, it is the one that recognizes the `<`.

Comment: Just make the command to execute `cmd /c xxx.exe < Input.txt`

Comment: As you can see in the title, I was hoping to do this using any IDE.